# Evaluate the sum to n terms : $\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{2x}{(x+1)(x+2)}+\frac{3x^2}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The main question is :

> Evaluate the sum to n terms : 
>   $$\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{2x}{(x+1)(x+2)}+\frac{3x^2}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}+\dots$$

My approach :

My first intuition was to make the series telescopic. Following is what I get as the general term.
Let $T_{r}$ denote the $r^{th}$ term.
Therefore, 
$$T_{r} = \frac{r.x^{r-1}}{(x+1)(x+2)\dots (x+r)}$$

I've spent a lot of time using different techniques to manipulate this term by which I can get a telescopic series, but to no avail. There may be different methods to solve this question, but I am interested only in approach involving telescopic series. I am a high school student so I may not understand a few advanced concepts. Please bear that in mind while providing hints or answers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Huh, this question stumps me.  I don't think you can solve it without doing anything advanced.  You could, however, rewrite the product using the factorial or gamma function.

Comment: I am not familiar wih the gamma function, and I only have a basic understanding of the factorial. I do not know how to apply factorial for non-integral numbers or variables.

Comment: Well, we usually use $(3/2)!=(3/2)\times(1/2)!$ for example, since the integer definition is given by $$n!=1\times2\times3\times\dots\times n$$

Comment: $$T_r=\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{r(-1)^{k+1}(-k)^{r-1}(k-1)!}{(r-k)!(x+k)}$$ in case someone could use this.

Comment: Would it not be possible to come up with the [partial fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Examples) of $T_r$?

Comment: That's what I've been trying. I'm beginning to doubt this series even becomes telescopic. I believe there must be a pattern hiding somewhere.

Comment: @Plopperzz Did you not see the comment above yours?

Comment: @Plopperzz You also have to consider the $n$ in the numerator.  And anyways, I've already decomposed the thing.  Either way, it seems like the wrong path to take.

Comment: @SimpleArt unfortunately not. :) I was distracted with checking out some exaples.

Comment: @Plopperzz Quick trick, `\ddot\smile` renders as $\ddot\smile$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice
$$\begin{align}\frac{rx^{r-1}}{\prod_{k=1}^r(x+k)}
&= \frac{rx^r}{\prod_{k=0}^r(x+k)}
= \frac{((x+r)-x)x^r}{\prod_{k=0}^r(x+k)}\\
&= \frac{x^r}{\prod_{k=0}^{r-1}(x+k)} - \frac{x^r}{\prod_{k=1}^r(x+k)}
= \frac{x^{r-1}}{\prod_{k=1}^{r-1}(x+k)} - \frac{x^r}{\prod_{k=1}^r(x+k)}
\end{align}
$$
has the form of a telescoping sum, we have
$$\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{rx^{r-1}}{\prod_{k=1}^r(x+k)}
= 1 - \frac{x^n}{\prod_{k=1}^n(x+k)}$$

Comment: Oh nice, I'd upvote if I could, but I used up all my votes today.  So I guess this is my upvote to you.

Comment: (+1) (Accepted) Nice! How did this click?

Comment: @AksharGandhi It is by trial and error. $$\frac{r}{\prod_{k=0}^r (x+k)} = \frac{(x+r)-x}{\prod_{k=0}^r (x+k)} = \frac{1}{\prod_{k=0}^{r-1}(x+k)} - \frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^r(x+k)}$$ is one of those identities that is useful to attack this sort of sums. I randomly modify it and find something that works.

Comment: Wow, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks again!

Comment: @achillehui My goodness, trial and error huh?  I probably could've sat here hopelessly for the entire day.

Comment: @achillehui I have found you can do this much much faster via a PFD like process, in which one chooses the denominators to come out as they did, and often times the numerator follows just as nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following similar problem

$$f_N(x,n)=\sum_{r=1}^N\frac{rx^{r-1}}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\dots(n+r)}=\sum_{r=1}^N\frac{rx^{r-1}n!}{(n+r)!}$$

Integrate $f_N(x,n)$ with respect to $x$:

$$\int f_N(x,n)dx=\int\sum_{r=1}^N\frac{rx^{r-1}n!}{(n+r)!}dx$$

$$=c+\sum_{r=1}^N\frac{x^rn!}{(n+r)!}$$

$$=c+n!e^xx^{-n}\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+N+1,x)}{\Gamma(n+N+1)}-\frac{\Gamma(n+1,x)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\right)$$

Thanks to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20x%5En%2F(a%2Bn)!%20n%3D1%20to%20c), where $\Gamma(x,y)$ is the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) and $\Gamma(x)$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Thus, we have

$$f_N(x,n)=\frac{d}{dx}n!e^xx^{-n}\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+N+1,x)}{\Gamma(n+N+1)}-\frac{\Gamma(n+1,x)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\right)$$

And your original problem:

$$\sum_{r=1}^NT_r=f_N(x,x)$$

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the gamma function. However, thank you for your approach and time!

Comment: @AksharGandhi That is sure fine.  I do recommend, if you've taken calculus, to learn a bit on the gamma function.  It is an interesting and useful function that appears relatively frequently in things.